# Text inputs required only when their div isn't hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I'm looking for some advice on a way to have a few inputs only be set as "required" if the div they're in isn't hidden.

Here is the javascript I use to show the hidden div:

```
function ShowHide(){
if(document.getElementById('addressY').checked){
    document.getElementById("addressT").style.display = "block";
} else {
    document.getElementById("addressT").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

And an example of the hidden DIV input forms:

```
<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="radios"><b>Did you find an address where the company accepts payments?</b></label>
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="radio"><label for="radios-1"><input id="addressY" name="spelling" onchange="ShowHide()" required="" type="radio" value="yes" /> Yes </label></div>

<div class="radio"><input id="addressN" name="spelling" onchange="ShowHide()" required="" type="radio" value="no" /> No</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="addressT" style="display: none;">&nbsp;
<div class="form-group"><b><label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Full Address">Please fill in the full address that you found.</label> </b>

<div class="col-md-4"><label for="radios-0">Make Check Payable To (Optional): <input class="form-control input-md" id="address1" name="address1" placeholder="" style="width: 100%;" type="text" /></label>    
</div>
```

You can see an example of the full form in action [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk_bulk_sandbox/hits/13126494/eyMMzcBrqn6yIIMrF_eijA.html?assignmentId=392CY0QWG2CAKLGYF2X57BKE8ZFI4Q&hitId=3UAU495MIIDHALOM21WQGSIEZ8JOUK&workerId=A310N8EXJNXVCA&turkSubmitTo=https%3A%2F%2Fworkersandbox.mturk.com).

If you can think of a better way to do this, I would love to hear this. I'm a relative beginner to javascript and jquery.

Comment: hiding and disabling both will do probably

Comment: is my answer helpful???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here if you hide element and disable the radio buttons then your problem is solved
so,

```
function ShowHide(){
if(document.getElementById('addressY').checked){
    document.getElementById("addressT").style.display = "block";
    for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
           radios[i].disabled = false;
        }
} else {
    document.getElementById("addressT").style.display = "none";
        var radios = document.querySelectorAll("[name='addresstype']")

        for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
           radios[i].disabled = true;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I just gave this solution a try and unfortunately I'm still running into the issue. The form is still not allowing submission even when the div is hidden. Any other potential solutions you can think of?

Comment: @Rob: I can't see jquery added in your page

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb now. That actually worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function ShowHide(){
if(document.getElementById('addressY').checked){

document.getElementById("addressT").style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("divWithRadioButtons").innerHTML = "Write your html code for those radio buttons and make them required"
} else {
document.getElementById("addressT").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("divWithRadioButtons").innerhtml="";
}
}
```

Comment: `innerHTML` (it's case sensitive) is not a function,  it's a property

Comment: @freefaller thanks for pointing out... I will edit it to document.getElementById("divWithRadioButtons").innerHTML = 'Your code'